# Custom notification "Target Object"

Tags: workflow, process-builder, notification

I've created a Custom notification as part of a process builder workflow. It monitors the creation of a specific child record of the "Lead" record type. When a child record is created that matches the specified criteria, a notification is generated to the Lead Owner.

However when clicking the notification it goes directly to the child object, when it would be better to go to the parent "Lead" record. In the process builder workflow the "Target Object" appears to be a potential candidate for changing where the notification leads, however it has only one option, the child object. Is there any way to have this link directly to the parent "Lead" record instead of the child record?

Picture of process builder node:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can customize what appears in the Process builder for `Target Object`. It's just the record that the Process Builder is on. You should be able to [select the appropriate Target Object Id in a flow](https://theeverydayadmin.com/2019/08/08/summer-19-new-feature-alert-have-you-combined-flow-custom-notifications-yet/), however.